# Local variables not present at Python's rdb debugging breakpoint (in celery task)

Tags: python, celery, remote-debugging, pdb

I am trying to [debug a celery task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/debugging.html) but the parameters and local variables aren't present when I telnet in:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.contrib import rdb

celery = Celery('tasks', broker="redis://localhost:6379/0")

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
  someVar = 3
  rdb.set_trace()
```

In a different terminal:

`telnet 127.0.0.1 6902` (or whatever the port number is)

`x`, `y` and `someVar` will all produce a name error like: `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: that is strange... are you sure you're in the correct stack frame?

Comment: @asksol, I guess not.  Do you know how I would find out?

Answer (score 2):

To check if you are in the current stack frame, use the `u` and `d` (up and down) to move up and down (http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands)

You can see which file you're in (it's written in the pdb prompt). Usually you have to go up once or twice to get to the right file, from what I've experienced